# $A/\operatorname{rad} A$ describes all isomorphism classes of simple A-modules Alperin I.2.5

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$. We wish to show that the number of matrix summands of $A/\operatorname{rad} A$ coincides with the number of isomorphism classes of simple A-modules.

It is clear that if $S$ is a simple $A$-module, hence a reperesentative of an isomorphism class of simple $A$-module, it is certainly a simple $A/\operatorname{rad}A$ module since $\operatorname{rad}A$ annihilates all simple $A$-modules. Thus, each representative $S_i$ of $A$ gives rise to a matrix summand $M_{n_i}(k)$ of $A/\operatorname{rad} A$ since each are composed of sums of a unique simple module. It only remains to be shown that each $M_{n_j}(k)$ arises in this fashion.

Suppose not and let $C$ be the unique simple module for some $M_{n_j}(k)$ which does not arise from a corresponding simple $A$-module $S_j$. We know that $C \cong L/\operatorname{rad} A$ where $L$ is a submodule of $A$ containing $\operatorname{rad} A$. So $\operatorname{rad} A$ is maximal in $L$/ This line of reasoning should lead to a contradiction (or another should as far as I can see) but I'm having trouble making the next leap. A little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be much simpler to prove it directly, then use contradiction.

It's a basic exercise to show that $k^n$ is a simple $M_n(k)$ module (it's on the site elsewhere.)  Therefore it is trivial to let the product of matrix rings operate on $k^n$ by ignoring everything outside one of the matrix rings, and use matrix multiplication on the elements of $k^n$.

That clearly makes a simple module corresponding to the factor you selected.

Comment: Im not sure I understand how this shows every such simple module arises from one in A (up to iso)

Comment: @AaronZolotor I thought from what you wrote you knew the classes of simple modules for $A$ and for $A/J(A)$ are identical?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to show. I'm sorry if my question was phrased unclearly.

Comment: @AaronZolotor any $R/I$ module is automatically an $R$ module. You can easily verify simplicity is also preserved.  So the simple sub modules between both rings are identical.  What remains is to show the simple modules of the product of matrix rings corresponds to the factors (one simple isotype per factor)

Comment: Simplicity is preserved since any R/I module is annihilated by I as an R-module and so must be simple as an R-module. So we see simple submoldules give rise to the matrix summands and any matrix summand must arise in this way. Thanks!